# Combine dataframes based on a shared key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a directory that each contains dataframes stored as csv files. Each dataframe has some columns, one of which is a key value which has a partner dataframe somewhere else in the directory (which uses the same key). I am trying to find a way to concatenate the two dataframes based on this key.

Each data-frame broadly looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
    my_key | variable 1 | variable 2  
----------------------------------------
     A           1             2      
     A           6             5      
     A           7             8
```

So, the key for this data-frame is A. I am essentially trying to find a way to find the other data-frame where A is the key. What I want to end up with is something like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
    df_key | variable 1 | variable 2 | variable 3 | variable 4
---------------------------------------------------------------
     A           1             2           3             4      
     A           5             6           7             8      
     A           9             10          11            12
```

I had initially thought to store data-frames into two separate data-frame lists, and then do some sort of vlookup type function on the key value between lists. But I'm not sure how to achieve this. Some pseudo-code that will hopefully explain what I'm trying to achieve would be something like:

```
for df1 in dflist_1:
    for df2 in dflist_2
        if df1[key] == df2[key]
            df1.concatenate(df2)
```

Columns between the two partner dataframes are unique, so there shouldn't be a problem concatenating them.

Comment: I would use `join` instead of `concatenate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a [JOIN](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join). This allows a user to combine two datasets based on a mutual key.

```
df_1.join(df_2, df_1.my_key == df_2.my_key, 'inner').show()
```